# Is there a way to slow down animations in web pages using devtools in there respective browser?

Tags: animation, browser

Sometimes I'm seeing some awesome animation on the web, but most of the time, the animation plays too fast for me to find out how it's transition.
I'm thinking if there is a tools which can slow down the animation, it will be easy to debug animation in the page.